# PHP array_replace only checked elements from $_POST

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post, form-submit

How can I replace **only array elements** submitted from a post?

I've got a form with multiple checkboxes, and I submit all into a PHP page where I want to replace an array from another.

**Form:**

```
$oldArray = array(
  "colors" => array(1 => "mandarin", "strawberry", "blueberry", "kiwi", "banana"),
  "other"  => array(1 => "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4")
);
```

**Destination page:**

```
$newArray = array(
  "colors" => array(1 => "orange", "red", "blue", "green", "yellow"),
  "other"  => array(1 => "example1", "example2", "example3", "example4")
);

print_r( array_replace($_POST['colors'], $newArray['colors']) );
```

If I check only two elements, "mandarin" and "kiwi", `array_replace` returns:

```
Array (
  [1] => orange <--- OK
  [2] => strawberry 
  [3] => blueberry 
  [4] => green  <--- OK 
  [5] => banana
)
```

How can I `echo` **only `$_POST`** elements?

e.g.

```
 Array (
  [1] => orange
  [4] => green 
)
```

Comment: array_replace goes off array keys. without seeing your form, you're probably got `$_POST['colors'][0]['orange']` and `$_POST['colors'][1]['green']` coming in, which means your keys DON'T match.

Comment: @MarcB `orange` and `green` are values, not keys. At least according to the info posted above.

Comment: yes, but unless OP set up the form to have `colors[5]` or whatever as the field names, the array keys in $_POST are NOT going to correspond to whatever the keys are in his array.

Comment: @MarcB my form structure is: 
`<form action="example.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <?php $oldArray = array( "colors" => array(1 => "mandarin", "strawberry", "blueberry", "kiwi", "banana"), "other" => array(1 => "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4") ); ?> <?php foreach($oldArray['colors'] as $color): ?> <input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="<?php echo $color ?>" > <?php echo $color ?> <?php endforeach; ?> <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </form>`

Comment: Instead of editing a solution in your question, you better post that as an answer if it adds anything new to the current ones. Consider accepting one of the answers that worked best for you.

Comment: @rene ?? none of the post here solved my problem, I only try to find a solution with your suggestion. Sorry but I don't understand your rude reply.

Comment: @simo Sorry, I didn't mean to be rude, I only try to help but my heritage makes that I'm to the point. I was referring to [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Our goal is to have questions only be a question and not be inter-leaved with edits and/or answers. That is were answers are for and we allow self-answers.  And as I can't judge the technical merits of your answer I want to prevent that you post an answer that basically copies one of the current answers because that is normally not appreciated.

Comment: @rene Ok I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I change my update, by answering my question, right? But it's not a solution. I don't know what I have to do now.

Comment: @simo OK, I see, you should try to make that part of the natural flow of your question. You might find [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged/270784#270784) helpful. I assume you already did find [ask] and the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link on that same page. I hope someone can help you out, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post the array key through. Try this:

```
$oldArray = array(
    "colors" => array(1 => "mandarin", "strawberry", "blueberry", "kiwi", "banana"),
    "other"  => array(1 => "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4")
);

echo '<select name="colors">';
foreach ($oldArray['colors'] as $key => $val)
{
    echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$val.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Then in your PHP page you receive you can do:

```
$newArray = array(
    "colors" => array(1 => "orange", "red", "blue", "green", "yellow"),
    "other"  => array(1 => "example1", "example2", "example3", "example4")
);

foreach($_POST['colors'] as $key)
{
    echo $newArray['colors'][$key];
}
```

Comment: Ehi Styphon! thank you for your suggest. 
My form look like this:

`<form action="example.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<?php 
$oldArray = array(
    "colors" => array(1 => "mandarin", "strawberry", "blueberry", "kiwi", "banana"),
    "other"  => array(1 => "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4")
);
?>

<?php foreach($oldArray['colors'] as $color): ?>

 <input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="<?php echo $color ?>" > 
<?php echo $color ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>`

Comment: @simo, what's the problem? Use the key as the check box value.

Comment: how can I pass the key position through post? Now first two checked elements replace first two positions of `combine_arr`.

Comment: Seriously?! Put the key in the value of the check box instead of the name, like my example does for a select box above!!! If you can't figure that out yourself, you shouldn't be programming. It's pretty basic.

Comment: I didn't understand you meaning to put the value instead of the name… you shouldn't answer too fast ;-)

Comment: Ehi! I did it with your suggestion! In the last foreach the correct echo is `echo $newArray['colors'][$key];` **Thank you so much!**

Comment: Glad you got it working, I've corrected my answer so the last echo is correct.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 print_r(array_intersect ($_POST['colors'],$newArray['colors']));
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, this return only an empty `Array ( )`